# Update GeoDjango models from KML?

Tags: postgis, kml, geodjango

I'm working in Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.4 with PostGIS extensions. I have a KML file, and I want to use it to **update** my geo fields. This is my model:

```
class PCT(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    boundary = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

This is my current code:

```
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
    from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
    ds = DataSource(options['filename'])
    layer_mapping = {
        'code': 'Name',
        'boundary': 'Unknown'
    }
    lm = LayerMapping(PCT, options['filename'],
                      layer_mapping, transform=False) # , unique='code')
    lm.save(strict=True)
```

It works OK, but if I run it a second time, it won't update any existing `PCT` fields - instead it creates new ones. This is a problem when I want to update the boundaries. (I can't just delete and re-create the fields, because there are foreign key dependencies.)

How can I use my KML file to **update** existing files?

@alex suggested trying this, but I'm getting an error:

```
    ds = DataSource(options['filename'])
    for layer in ds:
        for i in layer:
            code = str(i['Name'])
            geom = i.geom
            print geom

            geos_geom = geom.geos
            print geos_geom

            boundary = GEOSGeometry(geom)
            print boundary

            pct = PCT.objects.get(code=code)
            if pct:
                pct.boundary = geos_geom
                pct.save()
```

This throws an error at the `boundary = GEOSGeometry(geom)` line: `TypeError: Improper geometry input type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries.Polygon'>`.

The output from the print statements up to that point is as follows:

```
POLYGON ((-1.407325 54.593612 0,-1.423288 54.603131 0,-1.431455 54.595297 0 ...
SRID=4326;POLYGON Z ((-1.4073249999999999 54.5936120000000003 0.0000000000000000
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried simply passing a string to GEOSGeometry:

```
boundary = GEOSGeometry(str(i.geom))
pct = PCT.objects.get(code=code)
if pct:
  pct.boundary = boundary
  pct.save()
```

Perhaps this solves the issue? But now I get a different error on `pct.save()`:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
```

I can see by looking at the print statements that there is indeed a z column, but it's always zero, is it possible to get rid of this somehow?

Comment: Update: Related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300876/django-use-layermapping-to-update-an-existing-model I would prefer to use something other than LayerMapping if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed no need to use LayerMapping here: I can't test this right now so it may be bugged, but the idea is to test if your object exists first, and if it does, update the geometry.

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry


def update_pct():
     source = DataSource('some/path/to/the/file.kml') 
     for layer in source:
         for feat in layer:   
             code = feat['code'].value
             geom = feat.get_geoms()  # Get the feature geometry.
             geos_geom = geom.geos   # Get the geos representation of the geometry.
             boundary = GEOSGeometry(geom)  # Make a GeosGeometry object using the string representation.

             pct = PCT.objects.get(code=code)  # Note that .get() raises a DoesNotExist error if the object doesn't exist, so you will have to catch this.
             pct.boundary = boundary
             pct.save()
```

You probably also want to store details about *when* PCTs are updated somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I had to do `for layer in source: for feat in layer:` to get it to work, but this solved the problem. I just used `.get()` to get the PCT.